# Upgrade object literal to proper class instance in ScalaJS?

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

Does [scalajs](/questions/tagged/scalajs) have a mechanism to 'upgrade' an object literal to a proper instance of a type?

As an illustration:

Given a simple type defined like:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.ScalaJSDefined

@js.native
trait Point extends js.Object {
  val x: Int = js.native
  val y: Int = js.native
}

// or

@ScalaJSDefined @JSExport 
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) extends js.Object
```

and some function to use it:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport

@JSExport
object Foo {

  @JSExport
  def foo(point: Point) = ???
}
```

From the javascript environment, I want to be able to 'upgrade' an equivalent object literal value to be a proper `Point` instance, so the following behavior is the same:

```
var p1 = new Point(1, 1);
Foo.foo(p1);

var p2 = { x: 1, y: 1 };
Foo.foo(p2);
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming your first definition of `Point`, i.e.,

```scala
@js.native
trait Point extends js.Object {
  val x: Int = js.native
  val y: Int = js.native
}
```

an object literal `{ x: 1, y: 1 }` *already is* a valid instance of `Point`. It would also be better to use a Scala.js-defined JS trait rather than a native trait:

```scala
@ScalaJSDefined
trait Point extends js.Object {
  val x: Int
  val y: Int
}
```

If you use your other definition of `Point`, i.e.,

```scala
@ScalaJSDefined @JSExport 
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) extends js.Object
```

then the best way is to *also* define a `PointJS` that is a JS trait, and implicit conversions to/from `Point`:

```scala
@ScalaJSDefined
trait PointJS extends js.Object {
  val x: Int
  val y: Int
}

object PointJS {
  implicit def point2pointJS(p: Point): PointJS = new PointJS {
    val x = p.x
    val y = p.y
  }

  implicit def pointJS2point(p: PointJS): Point =
    Point(p.x, p.y)
}
```

and then, you will need a JS-friendly export, which uses a `PointJS` and not a `Point`:

```scala
@JSExport
object Foo {
  @JSExport
  def foo(point: Point) = ???

  @JSExport
  def foo(point: PointJS) = foo(point: Point)
}
```

Comment: if I want to be able to pattern match on the `Point` type in Scala code, does that imply I must use option 2 (ie, `Point` + `PointJS` + implicits?)

Comment: Yes, you need option 2 in that case.